# Is there a shorter way to write this condition in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```sql
SELECT IF(
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(current_year_holidays.july_4th), TIMESTAMP(t1.order_date), DAY) < 0,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(next_year_holidays.july_4th), TIMESTAMP(t1.order_date), DAY),
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(current_year_holidays.july_4th), TIMESTAMP(t1.order_date), DAY)
) AS days_until_july_4th
```

Specifically, I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid writing this line twice:

`TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(current_year_holidays.july_4th), TIMESTAMP(t1.order_date), DAY)`

It's written once to compare to `0`, and then written again for the `else_result`.

Can this be avoided?

Comment: Not sure - can you use `as` twice? If not often a CTE can resolve that. Not sure about google-bigquery though

Comment: not clear what are `current_year_holidays` and `next_year_holidays` - are those separate tables? i suggest to extend your example with all FROM and JOINs if any - at least the way how I would shorten your select statement really depends on those details

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Yes, they are separate tables, but for the purposes of my question you can just assume any statement could be there. I am just curious if there is some function that would avoid me having to repeat myself. I'm not really interested in restructuring the overall query to accomplish this, which is why the content of the arguments to `IF()` isn't really relevant.

Comment: ok. so in this case see my answer with dummy example

Comment: did you have chance to check the answer?

Answer (score 1):

> ...  but for the purposes of my question you can just assume any statement could be there

Ok, so below "verbose" dummy example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '2020-02-14 17:46:33.270196 UTC' order_date, 
    STRUCT('2020-02-12 17:46:33.270196 UTC' AS july_4th) next_year_holidays,
    STRUCT('2020-02-13 17:46:33.270196 UTC' AS july_4th) current_year_holidays
)
SELECT IF(
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(current_year_holidays.july_4th), TIMESTAMP(t1.order_date), DAY) < 0,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(next_year_holidays.july_4th), TIMESTAMP(t1.order_date), DAY),
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(current_year_holidays.july_4th), TIMESTAMP(t1.order_date), DAY)
) AS days_until_july_4th
FROM `project.dataset.table` t1
```

can be re-written as

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '2020-02-14 17:46:33.270196 UTC' order_date, 
    STRUCT('2020-02-12 17:46:33.270196 UTC' AS july_4th) next_year_holidays,
    STRUCT('2020-02-13 17:46:33.270196 UTC' AS july_4th) current_year_holidays
)
SELECT IF(
    diff < 0,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(next_year_holidays.july_4th), TIMESTAMP(t1.order_date), DAY),
    diff
) AS days_until_july_4th
FROM `project.dataset.table` t1,
UNNEST([TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(current_year_holidays.july_4th), TIMESTAMP(t1.order_date), DAY)]) diff
```

Hope, this gives you an idea